# Loop over country-waves and save the plots

Tags: r, foreach

I have a dataset with country over time (waves), structured as follow:

```
country wave income
1       1     1000
1       2     1400
1       3     900
..     ..     .. 
1       8     40000
2       1     3000
2       2     5432
```

And so on for 15 countries and 8 waves. I would like to run foreach country and foreach wave a qqplot on the total net household income to have a first detection of a Pareto distribution on the right tail and then save the plot. I tried to list the countries and waves with the following

```
countries<-unique(final_echp$country) 
waves<-unique(final_echp$wave)
```

And then using the foreach package I run:

```
foreach(c=countries)
  foreach(w=waves) %do% { 
    qqnorm(final_echp$hi100_eur)
    qqline(final_echp$hi100_eur)
    }
```

But it crashes, in the sense that is running for minutes without any results and I have to break it. How can I do the loop and save the plots with the corresponding country-wave title?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to plot a parameter for a bunch of countries and save plots in order to inspect them later. Why not save them to a pdf? Let me show you how to do it. I am going to use `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(country = c(rep('USA',20), rep('Canada',20), rep('Mexico',20)),
                 wave = c(1:20, 1:20, 1:20),
                 par = c(1:20 + 5*runif(20), 21:40 + 10*runif(20), 1:20 + 15*runif(20)))

countries <- unique(df$country)

plot_list <- list()
i <- 1

for (c in countries){
  pl <- ggplot(data = df %>% filter(country == c)) +
    geom_point(aes(wave, par), size = 3, color = 'red') +
    labs(title = as.character(c), x = 'wave', y = 'value') +
    theme_bw(base_size = 16)

  plot_list[[i]] <- pl
  i <- i + 1
}

pdf('path/to/pdf')
pdf.options(width = 9, height = 7)
for (i in 1:length(plot_list)){
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

The resulting pdf can be found at `path/to/pdf`.

Comment: your code perfectly works for a parameter, exactly. But what I would like to to do is to not plot a parameter, but the q-q plot of the total net household income with the normality line with the command qqnorm. I tried to readapt your code using `qqnorm(final_echp$hi100_eur)` instead of the ggplot, but it still take a lot of time and seems not working.

Comment: Paste a sample of your data, otherwise it will be hard to help.

Comment: I think is just a matter of dimension of the data frame, because once I break the execution, some graphs will be displayed. Also running the `dput()` is not feasible, if not written to an external file. By the way, it is a 15(countries) x 8(waves) matrix with the total net household income variable.